# find and sort selected words

Tags: cross-referencing, database

I am writing a book, where in i have to call back the selected words in different context. Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%For multiple index
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex   % is this required?
\makeindex[name=pl,title=Index of plants]
\makeindex[name=ch,title=Index of chemicals]


\begin{document}

I have discussed 3 plants in chapter 1. Rose\index[pl]{Rose},  banana\index[pl]{Banana}     
and mango\index[pl]{Mango}. 

In chapter 2, i have discussed 2 plants guava\index[pl]{Guava} and coconut\index[pl]{Coconut}. 

Totally, i have discussed  \ref{plants-number} plants in \ref{chemicals-number} chemicals in two chapters. 

Rose has benzene\index[ch]{Benzene}, toluene\index[ch]{Toluene} and 
methane\index[ch]{Methane}. Banana has toluene\index[ch]{Toluene}, 
ethane\index[ch]{Ethane} and ethyl alcohol\index[ch]{Ethyl alcohol}. 
Mango has methanol\index[ch]{Methanol}, ethyl alcohol\index[ch]{Ethyl alcohol} 
and benzene\index[ch]{Benzene}. Guava has ethane\index[ch]{Ethane}, 
acetic acid\index[ch]{Acetic acid}, formalin\index[ch]{Formalin}. 
Coconut has acetic acid\index[ch]{Acetic acid}, formalin\index[ch]{Formalin} 
and benzene\index[ch]{Benzene}.

Now i would like to have all the plants which has benzene, toluene etc.

\printindex
\indexprologue{\small In this index you’ll find only the plant names}
\printindex[pl]

\indexprologue{\small In this index you’ll find only the checicals}
\printindex[ch]


% We'll count the number of plants and of chemicals
\newcounter{items}
\makeatletter
\begingroup
% Define suitably \indexentry
\newcommand{\indexentry}[2]{%
 \@ifundefined{#1}
    {\refstepcounter{items}\expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname\@empty}
    {}}

% Let's count the plants
\begingroup
\setcounter{items}{0}
\input{pl.idx}\label{plants-number}
\endgroup

% Let's count the chemicals
\begingroup
\setcounter{items}{0}
\input{ch.idx}\label{chemicals-number}
\endgroup

\endgroup


 \end{document}
```

The question:  i would like to have all the plants which has benzene, toluene etc.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @egreg, it was already there in the post (before the code). Any way i have included at the end.

Comment: You have to link chemicals to plants also in the input.

Comment: @egreg, can u elaborate more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a first prototype:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\planthaschemicals}{m m}
  {
   \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
     { \plch_add:nn { ##1 } { #1 } }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \plch_add:nn #1 #2
  {
   \cs_if_exist:cF { g_plch_#1_seq }
     {
      \seq_new:c { g_plch_#1_seq }
      \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_plch_chems_seq { #1 }
     }
   \seq_gput_right:cn { g_plch_#1_seq } { #2 }
  }
\seq_new:N \g_plch_chems_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\showchemicals}{ }
  {
   \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_plch_chems_seq { \plch_chems_print:n { ##1 } }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \plch_chems_print:n #1
  {
   \par\medskip
   #1~is~connected~to~the~following~plants:
   \seq_map_inline:cn { g_plch_#1_seq } { ,~##1 }.
   \par\medskip
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\planthaschemicals{rose}{benzene,toluene,methane}
\planthaschemicals{banana}{toluene,ethane,ethyl alcohol}
\planthaschemicals{mango}{methanol,ethyl alcohol,benzene}
\planthaschemicals{guava}{ethane,acetic acid,formalin}
\planthaschemicals{coconut}{acetic acid,formalin,benzene}

\showchemicals

\end{document}
```

Of course you can put `\planthaschemicals` where you describe the plant.

There are various things to straighten up, but this should be the concept. Essentially, we define a sequence for each new chemical containing the plants to which this chemical is connected and we maintain a sequence containing the names of the chemicals, so that we can print it out.

One should need also to sort the sequences and to get a satisfying printout.